# php mysql query with GROUP_CONCAT & if statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, group-concat

I wrote an SQL query in PHP:

```
SELECT
    wp_news_contents.*,
    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT('wp_news_tags.tag_id=',tag_id SEPARATOR ' || ')
        FROM wp_news_tags
        WHERE content_id= 1
    ) AS sumset
FROM
    wp_news_contents,
    wp_news_tags
WHERE
    wp_news_contents.id = wp_news_tags.content_id
AND wp_news_tags.content_id != '1'
GROUP BY
    wp_news_contents.id
ORDER BY
    (SUM(IF(sumset ,1,0))) DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

`sumset` is true : `wp_news_tags.tag_id=777 || wp_news_tags.tag_id=529`

but the `IF` statement is not working. What is wrong and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please Can u add this on sqlfiddle

Comment: my database is very big & can't. sumset  is true but not executing.why?

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: your comment can,t help me!?

Comment: plz help me?! i don,t know It.